# ASP.NET: Get parent node text of selected node on an ASP.NET TreeView by Client Side JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to know the selected node's parent node text from a ASP.NET Treeview on client side.

Is there anyway to know this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Finally it is solved -

```
function GetSelectedNode() {
            var treeViewData = window["<%=treeView.ClientID%>" + "_Data"];
            if (treeViewData.selectedNodeID.value != "") {
                var selectedNode = document.getElementById(treeViewData.selectedNodeID.value);
                var ParentNode = selectedNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.previousSibling.innerText;
            }
            return ParentNode;
        }
```